# How can I change a font style for table of contents?

Tags: pdf, themes, wkhtmltopdf, tableofcontents

In my Drupal 8 website I am generating a pdf file from html code. It is done with the help of Entity Print module in combination with wkhtmltopdf engine. In the interface I could select the option to generate the table of contents. But now the issue for me is that I do not know how to theme table of contents, namely I want to assign "Times New Roman" font style.

In the entity-print.css under entity_print/css folder I have specified

```
@font-face  {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;

 }

body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

It affects the generated document itself, but not the Table of Contents

UPDATED: the entity-print.html.twig looks as following for me:

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>{{ title }}</title>
   {{ entity_print_css }}
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="page">
     {% for chapter in content%}
       <div class="section">
         {{ chapter }}
       </div>
     {% endfor %}
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a problem like this with entity print.

What i did eventually was to add some **inline styles** to my **twig template** for my pdf and got the results that i needed (both on html and on printed pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, the issue is still open for me. Do you mean I should edit my entity-print.html.twig template? I have updated my question, and twig template looks like this for me now. Should I add some inline-style for body tag?